# PHP why isnt my register and login scripts working?

Tags: php, html, mysql, registration

My php script for registry is not working, its returning

> Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Access denied for user '********'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/********/public_html/register.php on line 10

and

> Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: A link to the server could not be established in /home/********/public_html/register.php on line 10

Register.php

```
    <?php
    require('connect.php');
    // If the values are posted, insert them into the database.
    if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        $query = "INSERT INTO user (username, password, email) VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$email')";
        $result = mysql_query(!$query);
        if(!$result){
            $msg = "User Created Successfully.";
        }
    }
    ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>InfamousBurns - Register</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Form for logging in the users -->
<div>
<?php
    if(isset($msg) & !empty($msg)){
        echo $msg;
    }
 ?>
<h1 id="post">Register</h1>
<form action="" method="POST">
    <p id="post"><label>User Name : </label>
    <input id="username" type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" />
    </p>

    <p id="post"><label>E-Mail&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; : </label>
     <input id="password" type="email" name="email" required placeholder="vivek@email.com" />           </p>

     <p id="post"><label>Password&nbsp;&nbsp; : </label>
     <input id="password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" /></p>

    <a id="button" href="login.php">Login</a>
    <input  id="post" type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" />
    </form>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Access denied for user '**'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/**/public_html/register.php on line 10" - literally told you what's wrong, right there. Your aren't entering the correct username/password when attempting to connect.

Comment: Google the error. If you can't Google errors then you can't program. If you actually try to understand what your research says and you can't understand it then ask, don't ask us what's wrong when the error is just piercing your eyes. It's right there.

Comment: Regardless of that, you're exposed to SQL Injection. See [Why shouldn't I use mysql\_\* functions in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942).

Comment: $result = mysql_query(!$query);

Why do you have `(!$query)`?

Comment: i am entering the correct information i just checked it

Comment: @InfamousBurns read the error message carefully.

Comment: @InfamousBurns - no, you're not. The code doesn't make mistakes, the developer makes them. It says you entered incorrect information.

Comment: @InfamousBurns spefically the `using password: NO` part.

Comment: Your `connect.php` is most likely not loaded.

Comment: `$result = mysql_query(!$query);` the exclamation mark is too much too.

Comment: @GhostGambler It's using `require`. If that fails, the script produces a fatal E_COMPILE_ERROR level error. See http://php.net/require

Comment: Nevertheless it tries to establish the connection first with the `mysql_query` call. Then the `connect.php` is empty or whatever.

Comment: connect.php http://img30.imageshack.us/img30/8851/uyrn.png

Comment: SERIOUSLY? You are CLOSING the connection at the end of the file.

Comment: @InfamousBurns you're far better to add the code to your question instead of an image. Just X out your credentials.

Comment: @GhostGambler i've just started php 2 hours ago

Comment: Sorry, but this was really... like ... you know what I mean ;)

Comment: @InfamousBurns stop using `mysql_*` functions. They are deprecated. Instead use PDO or mysqli. Do it right from the beginning.

Comment: @Mike ive been told this

Comment: @InfamousBurns you should listen then... As it is now, if your script ever did actually manage to connect to the server, you are wide open to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: AND definitely look into http://php.net/password_hash. If you don't have PHP 5.5 look in the comments for the compatibility functions. **DO NOT STORE PASSWORDS IN PLAIN TEXT. EVER.**

Comment: @Mike its just a test site it

Comment: @InfamousBurns it's still not a good habit to get into.

Answer (score 0):

This happening because in "connect.php" your details to the MySQL database are not correct, because you haven't posted the actual connect.php details I can only assume that you've misspelt something.

**EDIT 1:**

Where you have

```
$selected = mysql_select_db($dbhandle);
```

change it to

```
$selected = mysql_select_db($mysql_database);
```

**EDIT 2**

Can I also suggest using PDO instead... example below for db connection below

```
<?php
    $host = "host";
    $user = "username";
    $pass = "pass";
    $db = "database name";

    try {
        $link = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db",$user,$pass);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        die();
    }
```

Of course this means having to change your SQL queries around a little bit and use prepared statements instead, I'm sure you can find some help for it online though

Comment: I would assume from `using password: NO` that the password is not getting passed to `mysql_connect`.

Comment: I wouldn't echo `$e->getMessage()` to the browser. With a failed connection it will echo your connection credentials in plain text.

Comment: @Mike good point... it is merely for testing purposes to check the credentials upon fail. Will take that part out

Answer (score 0):

If the login information is correct check the location of the file. It looks like connect.php should be in the public_html directory based on the way you are including it in Register.php. If its in a subdirectory or something make sure you are using the correct path in the require() function. And make sure any capital letters are capitalized as normal when using file locations.